# Smooth Scrolling In RecycleView like Pinterest Application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I want to Apply smooth scroll in Recycle view like Pinterest Application

```
RecyclerView my_view = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        my_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        my_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Now Currently I used this code.

Right now `RecyclerView` is scrolling too fast. I want to slow down scrolling speed so user can actually fell the smooth scroll.

Comment: So, whats your question ?

Comment: @Kedarnath Right now RecyclerView is scrolling too fast. I want to slow down scrolling speed so user can actually fell the smooth scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control Smooth scroll in recycler view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803319/control-smooth-scroll-in-recycler-view)