# How to make RecyclerView scroll smoothly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, gridlayoutmanager

This is more like a generic question, but after lot of search and try I am not able to understand why this is so difficult to achieve. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28853254/1273407) is the closest answer I can find but still unable to implement.

To be specific I am using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. All I want is the grid layout to scroll smoothly (like default gallary app) ,nothing fancy, but the default implementation of grid layout manager scrolls the view in a 'jerky' manner. I tried to implement the method from above link but unsuccessfully.

I also tried to implement LinearSmoothScroller but I am not sure how to implement computeScrollVectorForPosition method. [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSmoothScroller.html#computeScrollVectorForPosition(int)) on computeScrollVectorForPosition literally has 0 words.

I found [this 3 part tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/scrolling-recyclerview-part-1/), but it was of very little help. So, all I want to ask is: can there be some kind of template code which we can implement in LinearSmoothScroller or by extending RecyclerView.SmoothScroller and achieve smooth scrolling ? Even if the code depends on number of items and items per row in gridlayout, there has to be some method to do it easily. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: "Am I missing something here ?" -- perhaps you should determine why your existing code is "jerky", using tools like Traceview, `StrictMode`, and so on.

Comment: @commonsWare So  you mean default implementation of GridLayoutManager should scroll the gridview smoothly ? I am sorry if I sound noob, I am quite new to Android Programming.

Comment: "So you mean default implementation of GridLayoutManager should scroll the gridview smoothly ?" -- yes, at least for my definition of "smoothly". The typical source of "jerky" scrolling in Android is the app taking too much time on the main application thread updating the UI. In the case of `RecyclerView`, this would mean taking too much time in `onBindViewHolder()` or possibly in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Those each need to return in sub-millisecond times, meaning you cannot do disk I/O or network I/O in them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your answer, I think I found the problem. I am using `holder.photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(itemList.get(position).getAbsolutePath()));` on onBindViewHolder() and the image file is around 100kb each with about a dozen images in the list. I will try to do a better implementation of it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The typical source of "jerky" scrolling in Android is the app taking too much time on the main application thread updating the UI. In the case of `RecyclerView`, this would mean taking too much time in `onBindViewHolder()` or possibly in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Those each need to return in sub-millisecond times, meaning you cannot do disk I/O or network I/O in them.

> think I found the problem. I am using holder.photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(itemList.get(position).get‌​AbsolutePath())); on onBindViewHolder() and the image file is around 100kb each with about a dozen images in the list

Yes, that will be doing disk I/O and image decoding on the main application thread. That will be slow enough to cause jank in the UI (i.e., "jerky" scrolling).

Consider using an image loading library, like Picasso or Universal Image Loader, as they can populate your `ImageView` from the bitmap asynchronously.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoTable) uses Universal Image Loader to help populate the contents of a `RecyclerView` (with `GridLayoutManager`), with the data source being the available videos on the device.

Comment: Thank you, I will check them and implement. In the mean time how about using [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) simple solution rather than using a seperate library ?

Comment: @rockfight: Because that has little to do with your problem. The focus of that page is memory efficiency, not main application thread time.

Comment: UIL does not work while image resides in sd card (path of file starts with `/storage`. I used `Glide` for this purpose, and it provided a perfect solution to my problem

Comment: This is work for me. I face same issue with image large size. When we set image in `ImageView` using `Bitmap` then it work charms as @CommonsWare answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare, in my app the recyclerview scrolling is not smooth, since i am inflating views inside onBindViewHolder, is there any alternative way to add a view without layout inflater.

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil: Inflation is unlikely to be the problem; it would take you just about as much time to create the views directly via Java constructors and setters. Use method tracing in your IDE to determine exactly where your problem lies.

Answer (score 49):

Add this wherever you have declared `RecyclerView` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
mRecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

> `setNestedScrollview(false)` does the work for you.

Answer (score 17):

I just faced this problem, and disabling nested scroll fixed it.
Do it like this:

```
yourRecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Or you can change the value in xml file where you defined RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/yourRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Arman i use RecyclerView within NestedScrollView after that i got this. But now it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

I just faced this problem, and i got 
I put the `RecyclerView` in `ScrollView` 
So please never put the `RecyclerView` inside the `ScrollView` that may also cause.

```
mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
```

That always return a fixed value. And also check

```
recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

I made the scrolling smooth by overriding the `calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)` method:

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    protected CenterLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new CenterSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private class CenterSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {

        CenterSmoothScroller(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateDtToFit(int viewStart, int viewEnd, int boxStart, int boxEnd, int snapPreference) {
            return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2);
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return 0.5f; //pass as per your requirement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: overwrite `calculateSpeedPerPixel` work for me, the default will make recycler view like jumping when calling `smoothScrollToPosition(position)`, but when overwrite this method and return 0.5f works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

Comment: so which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Picasso" library to load image asynchronously, and also make sure that the size of the image which you load is similar to the size of image view in the layout, using the `fit()` function. Also, if you are using a recycler view inside the scroll view, make sure to set `nested scrolling` to false.

I solved my issue using the above three methods

Answer (score 0):

Use a library as said by other comments in here. Also make sure you do not have Recyclerviews nested within a Scrollview. This was one of the reason why mine previously wasn't so smooth.

Answer (score 0):

**After 3 days** spend in it, I solved the smooth scroll issue in my project.

The problem is `<layer-list>` drawable set in the background of `item_user.xml` file so it takes **GPU time for rendering** that's why scrolling not smooth.

Don't use `<layer-list>` or any other complex drawable in adapter item.

Answer (score -4):

just add this

```
animateLayoutChanges = true
```

in recyclerview xml

Comment: so which is it?