# Why ConstraintLayout slower than LinearLayout in RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm changing the xml item of recyclyerView from LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout.
When I'm scrolling the recyclerView horizontal, it lags and renders very slowly than LinearLayout.

**ConstraintLayout**

[image: ConstraintLayout]

**LinearLayout**

[image: LinearLayout]

Here i am sharing my xml for ConstraintLayout.

**my ConstraintLayout Item**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/merchant_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_img"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:transitionName="profile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        tools:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="72dp"
        android:minWidth="72dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/blackFont"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/merchant_img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/merchant_img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/merchant_img"
        tools:text="Chili's" />

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_offer_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/redColor"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_distance"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/merchant_offer_type"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/merchant_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/merchant_name"
        app:textBold="bold"
        tools:text="25%" />

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_offer_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/blackFont"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_distance"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/merchant_name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/merchant_offer_percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/merchant_name"
        tools:text=" | Refund " />

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:lines="1"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textColor="@color/greyFont"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:visibility="gone"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/merchant_img"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/merchant_img"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/merchant_offer_percent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**my LinearLayout Item**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/merchant_layout"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_img"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:transitionName="profile"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        tools:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/merchant_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="72dp"
        android:minWidth="72dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/blackFont"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Chili's" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/merchant_offer_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/redColor"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:textBold="bold"
            tools:text="25%" />

        <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/merchant_offer_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blackFont"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text=" | Refund " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.max.xclusivekotlin.customViews.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/greyFont"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Show your code how you are rendering.

Comment: Yea..please post the xml and java codes..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Relative Layout:**

`RelativeLayout` is an approach to actualize complex formats with level (one level of settling) outline. By its outline, it's overlaying things, not at all like `LinearLayout` that never does that Its name says independent from anyone else, `RelativeLayout` is awesome at situating things in respect to other. Suppose you have undetermined view width and you need to put a thing to one side of it and to the base of it in the meantime. You can do that with `LinearLayout`, however, it would take two settled, with `RelativeLayout` it got way cleaner.

**Constraint Layout:**

The center is `RelativeLayout` where things can overlay. Be that as it may, what makes `ConstraintLayout` awesome is it can supplant the various designs: Frame, Relative, Linear. Truly, there are numerous different formats, yet those are wrappers What I like about `ConstraintLayout` is that it's extremely awesome at utilizing as a part of Design mode before I didn't care for it by any means. For the most part in view of the poor execution of my fair equipment (for Android Studio) and regular rendering bugs `ConstraintLayout` properties really are so long and appalling that it's better utilizing it Design mode. It can control position and measurements (not at all like `RelativeLayout`) of perspectives. Keep in mind, that parameters beginning with layout_ are implied for wrapping format. The view itself doesn't deal with those

So you can utilize your most loved weight from `LinearLayout` in `ConstraintLayout` by imperative chains, land left/right/top/base of from `RelativeLayout`, overlay things like in straightforward `FrameLayout` I think no one uses `GridLayout`, it's far excessively disappointing, constantly favored settled `LinearLayout`, with `ConstraintLayout` you can do that effortlessly

**Constraint Layout Disadvantage:**

Despite the fact that it's awesome, outline mode still isn't as immaculate as XML. It gets jumbled simple, you have to zoom in on perspectives and it drives you to have simply `ConstraintLayout`, in the event that you endeavor to include some settled design – you'd think twice about it.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe for lot of constraint you are using in the `ConstraintLayout` or maybe `RecyclerView` performance.

i recommend you using `RelativeLayout`

these link can help you :

[Improve RecyclerView performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133502/8621930)

[RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38671211/8621930)

[How Make RecyclerView Smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249252/how-to-make-recyclerview-scroll-smoothly)

Comment: ok i knew about that, now i will used RelativeLayout until google fix this bug
or someone tell me how i should used ConstraintLayout for RecyclerView item

Answer (score 0):

Because ConstraintLayout is slower than FrameLayout, and maybe other layouts (I've only tested FrameLayout). I have a ConstraintLayout with 5 items in it, its `onMeasure` method costs about 50ms. When I change this ConstraintLayout to a FrameLayout, its `onMeasure` method costs just 1 or 2ms.