# get scroll Y of RecyclerView or Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-recyclerview

I have created a activity `Webview` content placed in `Recyclerview`.
I want to get the scroll Y position when I scroll webview.
I tried `Webview.getScrollY()`, `Webview.getY()`, `RecyclerView.getScrollY()`, `RecyclerView.getY()`,... but it do not work fine. I can't get current scroll Y.
Is there any suggest for get scroll Y of `Webview` or `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Try `view.computeVerticalScrollOffset()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) for the RecyclerView and a [View.OnScrollChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/view/View.OnScrollChangeListener.html) for the webview.

You'll have to keep track of the total scroll yourself, like this:

```
private int mTotalScrolled = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                mTotalScrolled += dy;

            }
        });

    ...

}

private int getScrollForRecycler(){
    return mTotalScrolled;
}
```

Comment: I've tried `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`. But `onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)` method in this just get `dy` not y position.

Comment: extended my answer for you

Comment: Yes, it is right, but partially. When I use ```linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(int, int)``` to manually change the position, I can't get the delta Y, namely dy is always 0 during this process. So I regard it not reliable enough and need a better way.

Comment: Not reliable, this is not the answer. After scrolling a bit you easily get to a point where the manually accumulated y is out of sync. The RecyclerView is all the way up and I still get a non-zero y. I'll keep looking.

Comment: `recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()` would be a better answer than this.

Comment: Not really. `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` isn't the same as the number of pixels scrolled. RV uses it for showing a scrollbar and it's value is very imprecise.

Comment: Trying to access `mTotalScrolled ` inside `onScrolled` crashes the app.

Comment: this runs into issues when using notifyItemRemoved in the adapter since the removed item causes mTotalScrolled to change without calling onScroll

Answer (score 20):

`computeVerticalScrollOffset()`is more convenient at this situation as @Pkmmte mentioned.

```
mTotalScrolled  = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
```

Comment: it doesn't return scrollY of recycler, it returns _The vertical offset of the scrollbar's thumb_