# Recyclerview controll speed of scroll using scrollBy method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Dears I've managed to control the speed of scrolling using the scrollToPosition method via custom linear layout manager.

But I've used scrollBy(int dx, int dy) method and the scroll speed is still the default scrolling speed of the recyclerview speed.

Any Idea how to change the scrolling speed of this particular method?

Here's my layout's code:

```
    package com.arabiaweather.maater.screens.livesatellite.components

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.PointF
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearSmoothScroller
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.util.DisplayMetrics

class CustomLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {

    var millisPerInch = 250.0f

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout) {}

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?, position: Int) {

        val linearSmoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context) {

            override fun computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition: Int): PointF? {
                return this@CustomLinearLayoutManager
                        .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition)
            }

            override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
                return millisPerInch / displayMetrics.densityDpi
            }
        }
        linearSmoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller)
    }

    override fun startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller: RecyclerView.SmoothScroller?) {
        super.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }

    override fun scrollToPositionWithOffset(position: Int, offset: Int) {
        super.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)
    }


}
```

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition works fine, however smoothScrollBy doesn't respect the speed I've set for my layout manager, and I can't use scrollToPosition as the views i'm scrolling are complex and I need exact locations to scroll too, if not for the NDA I would've put my screen design

Comment: I you are after a solution for controlling the speed of the scroll, to scroll faster to more distant positions have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63643036/3833411

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way.

Looking at the Android code, I see that the ViewFlinger class contains a method that allows set the scroll by distance AND the velocity:

```
class ViewFlinger implements Runnable {
     ...
    ...
    public void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy, int vx, int vy) {
                smoothScrollBy(dx, dy, computeScrollDuration(dx, dy, vx, vy));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to access this function from the RecyclerView as RecyclerView.mViewFlinger is private. I wish there was a way to access it from an inherited class.

Another way would be to extend the ViewFlinger class and override the function computeScrollDuration(), but I also don't see a way to do that (the class ViewFlinger is package-private in RecyclerView)

```
        private int computeScrollDuration(int dx, int dy, int vx, int vy) {
            final int absDx = Math.abs(dx);
            final int absDy = Math.abs(dy);
            final boolean horizontal = absDx > absDy;
            final int velocity = (int) Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
            final int delta = (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            final int containerSize = horizontal ? getWidth() : getHeight();
            final int halfContainerSize = containerSize / 2;
            final float distanceRatio = Math.min(1.f, 1.f * delta / containerSize);
            final float distance = halfContainerSize + halfContainerSize
                    * distanceInfluenceForSnapDuration(distanceRatio);

            final int duration;
            if (velocity > 0) {
                duration = 4 * Math.round(1000 * Math.abs(distance / velocity));
            } else {
                float absDelta = (float) (horizontal ? absDx : absDy);
                duration = (int) (((absDelta / containerSize) + 1) * 300);
            }
            return Math.min(duration, MAX_SCROLL_DURATION);
        }
```

Ideally the RecyclerView.java class would add these lines to make it possible:

```
    public void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy, int vx, int vy, Interpolator interpolator) {
        if (mLayout == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot smooth scroll without a LayoutManager set. "
                    + "Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.");
            return;
        }
        if (mLayoutFrozen) {
            return;
        }
        if (!mLayout.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            dx = 0;
        }
        if (!mLayout.canScrollVertically()) {
            dy = 0;
        }
        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            mViewFlinger.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy, vx, vy, interpolator);
        }
    }
```

So I don't see a way as of now.