# Recyclerview items vibrates while scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Recyclerview showing media but when I scrolls items flickers or vibrates. I have tried many options mentioned in post like

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803319/android-control-smooth-scroll-over-recycler-view[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803319/android-control-smooth-scroll-over-recycler-view%5Bsolution) 1][1]

My xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/card_backgroundColor"
    tools:context=".ui.matcheduser.GalleryViewFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcGallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
            android:background="?attr/card_backgroundColor" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_galleries"
        style="@style/TextViewHeadStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Gallery data is empty."
        android:textColor="?attr/customIconColorST"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="?attr/popupBackgroundColor"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And code for Adapter:

```
private void initViews() {
        mBinding.swipeToRefresh.post(() -> mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(true));
        mViewModel.getGalleriesFromDB(mSettings.getUserId()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<GalleryModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<GalleryModel> galleryModels) {
                mBinding.progressCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                LOG.i(TAG, "Set Adapter : " + galleryModels.size());
                    if (mAdapter == null && galleryModels.size() > 0) {
                        galleryModelList = galleryModels;
                        mBinding.tvNoGalleries.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(mContext, galleryModels, GalleryViewFragment.this, requireActivity());
                        mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                        mBinding.rcGallery.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                        isNextFetchAllowed = false;
                        mBinding.rcGallery.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                        mBinding.rcGallery.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    } else if (galleryModels.size() > 0) {
                        galleryModelList = galleryModels;
                        if (isDataChanged) {
                            generalViewModel.setGalleryChange(galleryModelList);
                        }
                        isNextFetchAllowed = false;
                        mAdapter.addItem(galleryModels);
                    }

                if (mBinding.swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });

        mBinding.rcGallery.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == 0 && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    onBottomReached(Integer.parseInt(mViewModel.pageFetch));
                }
            }
        });

        mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            if (NetworkUtility.isConnected(mContext)) {
                mViewModel.fetchNextGalleryList(mViewModel.STARTING_PAGE, mSettings.getDeviceId());
                galleryModelList.clear();
            } else {
                mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        mViewModel.noDataFound().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), aBoolean -> {
            if (aBoolean) {
                mBinding.progressCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mViewModel.setNoDataFound(false);
                if (mViewModel.pageFetch.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    mBinding.tvNoGalleries.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mBinding.tvNoGalleries.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        mViewModel.getServerErrorValue().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), errorString -> {
            if (!errorString.isEmpty()) {
                mBinding.swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                mBinding.tvNoGalleries.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBinding.tvNoGalleries.setText(errorString);
                mViewModel.resetServerErrorValue();
            }
        });

        mViewModel.getDuplicateError().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), errorCode -> {
            if (errorCode == 501) {
                UtilHelper.resetSettingAndLogout(requireActivity(), mSettings);
                mViewModel.resetErrorValue();
            }
        });

    }

My Adapter code: 


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        GalleryModel galleryModel = galleryModelList.get(position);
        loadMedia(viewHolder, galleryModel, viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.media, position);
    }

    private void loadMedia(ViewHolder viewHolder, GalleryModel galleryModel, ImageView postImage, int position) {
        try {
            String path = UtilHelper.getFileApi() + "/" + galleryModel.getMediaName().trim();
            File file = UtilHelper.createExternalFileForDownloaded(context, path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
            boolean isVideoFile = UtilHelper.isVideo(Uri.parse(galleryModel.getMediaName()), context);

            try {
                String localeName = galleryModel.getMdOriginalType();
                File localeFile = UtilHelper.createExternalFileForDownloaded(activity, localeName.substring(localeName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));

                if (localeFile.exists() && !file.exists()) {
                    boolean renamed = localeFile.renameTo(file);
                    if (renamed) {
                        LOG.d(TAG, "Image File renamed...");
                    } else {
                        LOG.d(TAG, "Image not renamed...");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            }

            postImage.setTag(path);
            if (!isVideoFile) {
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                postImage.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        onItemClickListener.onImageClick(galleryModel, null, !galleryModel.isMdPrivate() ? null : path, position);
                    } else {
                        onItemClickListener.onImageClick(galleryModel, null, file.getAbsolutePath(), position);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.download.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                try {
                    if (!isDownloading) {
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            isDownloading = true;
                            downloadAsyncTask = new DownloadVideoAsyncTask(UtilHelper.getDirectory(activity), pDialog, this);
                            downloadAsyncTask.execute(path, "1");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Already downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            });
            viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.play.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                try {
                    try {
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            onItemClickListener.onPlayVideo(path, true);
                        } else {
                            onItemClickListener.onPlayVideo(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        LOG.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            });

            if (!file.exists()) {
                Glide.with(context).load(path).apply(options).into(postImage);
            } else {
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.gallerItemBinding.imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(context).load(file).apply(options).into(postImage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any log cat message? like the app is working too much work on the main thread

Comment: I am just using glide with cache enabked to load images in recyclerview. Other than that I am not using any network call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` added in manifest file at application level because of this UI flicker was occurring. After removing this from manifest and now its working fine.